# Windows 7 automatically install usb driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, android

I have tried to install usb driver for Samsung arndale on Windows 7. Now it has two entries in Device Manager. I can not uninstall the one with question mark. If I uninstall both of them, when I plug in the hardware, Windows 7 will automatically install both of the entries when the circuit pulg in. I don't get the chance to choose the right driver. When I try to update the wrong driver, it says found the driver but can not install it.